# Can we specify Dockerfile path when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I understand that Elastic Beanstalk picks up the `Dockerfile` in project root by default and builds the image accordingly. My project has multiple `Dockerfile` files, and I want to use a specific `Dockerfile` for EB (not the one in project root). Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible.

If you are not using Docker Compose, then the application must include either a `Dockerfile` or a `Dockerrun.aws.json` file, and those must be located at the root of the zip. From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html#docker-configuration.no-compose):

> The two files must be at the root, or top level, of the .zip archive.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using a `docker-compose.yml` file per  [AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html.).

See [Compose File build reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build), but in short - in the `docker-compose.yml` file specify:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: ${your_sub_directory}/${your_Dockerfile_name}
```

Comment: I don't want to use `docker-compose` because it builds some other containers as well. We are using the same repo for multiple services. I only want to build a specific image for EB without using `docker-compose`.

Comment: Per the answer you can specify the dockerfile path in the build steps, it should not be building other containers?